# RSpec Rails Login Filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, authlogic, rspec2, rspec-rails

I recently switched started using rspec-rails(2.6.1) with my Rails(3.0.8) app. I'm used to Test::Unit, and I can't seem to get a filter working for my test methods. I like to keep things as DRY as possible, so I'd like to set up a filter that I can call on any test method that will login as an Authlogic user before the test method is called. I tried accomplishing this by using an [RSpec filter](http://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-5/dir/hooks/filters) in spec_helper.rb:

```
config.before(:each, :login_as_admin => true) do 
  post "/user_sessions/create", :user_session => {:username => "admin", :password => "admin"}   
end
```

Then I use it in the corresponding test method(in this case spec/controllers/admin_controller_spec.rb):

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe AdminController do  
  describe "GET index" do        
    it("gives a 200 response when visited as an admin", :login_as_admin => true) do   
      get :index
      response.code.should eq("200")
    end    
  end
end
```

However, I get this error when I run **rspec spec**:

```
Failures:

  1) AdminController GET index gives a 200 response when visited as an admin
     Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
     RuntimeError:
       @routes is nil: make sure you set it in your test's setup method.
```

Blech. Can I only send one HTTP request per test? I also tried stubbing out my authenticate_admin method(inside the config.before block), without any luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way at the moment to do what you're trying to do in a globally defined `before` hook. The reason is that `before` hooks are executed in the order in which they get registered, and those declared in `RSpec.configure` are registered before the one that `rspec-rails` registers internally to set up the controller, request, response, etc.

Also, this has been reported to https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/391.

Comment: Thanks for the info, David. I'm glad to see it's been reported already. Also, thanks for your work on RSpec, it really is a handy testing framework.

Answer (score -1):

You should use shulda's macrons. To use shoulda modify your spec_helper.rb

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Clearance::Shoulda::Helpers
end
```

And then can setup filter in controller spec like

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe AdminController do  
  fixture :users

  before(:each) do
    sign_in_as users(:your_user)
  end
  describe "GET index" do        
    it("gives a 200 response when visited as an admin", :login_as_admin => true) do   
      get :index
      response.code.should eq("200")
    end    
  end
end
```

Comment: That won't solve the issue the OP is trying to solve, as the bits that `sign_in_as` needs to work (controller, etc) won't be set up before a `before` hook defined in `RSpec.configure`.