# Is the @routes be created after "before(:all)" and before "before(:each)"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

In the rails project, when i write some controller's spec like this:

```
describe "POST 'create'" do
context "valid user" do
    before(:all) {
  @user_attributes = Factory.attributes_for(:user)
  @user = Factory(:user, @user_attributes)
  post :create, :user=>@user_attributes
}
specify { flash[:notice].should eq("Welcome")}
specify { response.should redirect_to(:action=> :index) }
end
end
```

I got some errors like this:

Failure/Error: post :create, :user=>@user_attributes

> RuntimeError:
>
> @routes is nil: make sure you set it in your test's setup method.
>
> # ./spec/controllers/sessions_controller_spec.rb:22
>
> # ./magazine_slave.rb:22:in `run'
> # magazine_slave_provider.rb:17

When I change before(:all) to before(:each),the test will be pass.

Is the @routes be created after "before(:all)" and before "before(:each)"

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think this is answered in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394414/rspec-rails-login-filter).  From the conversation [here](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/391), it looks like a fix might be coming.